# Macbook Air 2019 Black Screen USB Boot

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, startup, unix

I flashed my USB with an ISO and when I tried to boot the USB, I was given a black screen. I checked to see if it was just improperly flashed, but the USB would boot up on my other laptop just fine. Its GPT, FAT32 and was Flashed with a Fedora ISO. I've tried many different options. MBR and different ISO images like Acronis True Image and Debian. I used rufus on a windows machine to flash the flash drive. I had installed Windows on my MacBook Air without BootCamp through the same process that I am currently trying to get to work. I was able to get my USB booted prior to my Windows 10 Installation. I reinstalled Mac OS x Catalina and made sure that the security settings in recovery mode were set to No Security for Secure Boot and Allow booting from external or removable media for Allowed Boot Media. I have tried to reset the NVRAM and SMC. However, everything that I have tried has ended up in vain. The only thing that I haven't tried is buying a new flash drive to see if it really is just a problem with my USB. However, it would work on my other machine, so i don't know if that is truly an issue. The reason I'm not using BootCamp is because I only have a 128GB SSD. There's not enough space for me to feel free with using two operating systems.

Comment: Windows ISO works, Linux does not work I think because of T2 Chip.

Comment: Can you add more information that would help identify what is the other laptop?

Comment: My other laptop was a razer blade 15. I found my answer though. However, I have not been able to install a Linux distribution due to a lack of drivers. I was able to find Linux distributions modified to be boot-able for the newer MacBooks, but I was not very successful in installing one of those operating systems. I am able to boot a Windows installation media, but I have not been able to fully go throughout the installation process so far. Yet I know that It can be done. I just haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS have both been successfully installed on the internal drive of the 2018 Mac mini with the T2 chip. In other words, there are Ask Different and Ask Ubuntu answers posted stating this.  I do not know about a 2019 MacBook Air.

Comment: I have successfully installed windows 10 in the past. I have gotten a modified ISO for fedora and arch Linux to boot, but fedora wouldn't load past the loading screen and arch Linux would freeze every time i used a disk utility program to partition the hard drive. Windows 10 is now giving me a "Windows could not update the computer's boot configuration. Installation cannot proceed." whenever I try to install the operating system. The only thing I haven't tried is using a different USB but the images work on my other machine. So to me, there is a problem with the MacBook.

Comment: Did you copy the Windows Support Software to the Windows installer USB flash drive? Which version of the Windows 10 ISO are you using?

Comment: I used Win10_20H2_v2_English_x64 to install Windows the previous time and I tried to use that same ISO to install windows again but then I downloaded the newest one and it still had some kind of error. But yes, I have the Windows Support drivers save to an external SSD. The installation fails half way through the installation. I actually just got Fedora to boot an install on my MacBook! I don't know why it booted this time, but it took more than like 4 times.

Comment: I couldn't use WiFi with Fedora and didn't want to try and go through a process specifically meant for a MacBook Pro so i tried to reinstall windows. and lo and behold, for absolutely no reason, it decided to work this time!